# display a variable between simple quote

Tags: bash, variables, quotes, backslash

I need to run a command in a bash script. Here is an example of my code and the command to run :

```sh
command(){
    $(randomCommand -a '${1}')
}

command "Hello world"
```

Actually the final command look like this:

```sh
randomCommand -a '${1}'
```

But i want this:

```sh
randomCommand -a 'Hello world'
```

It's normal, variables aren't interpreted between simple quotes, but these simple quotes are required for my program. So... i just have to escape quotes with backslashes ?
If i use backslash \ like this :

```sh
command(){
    $(randomCommand -a \'${1}\')
}

command "Hello world"
```

the command will look like that :

```sh
randomCommand -a \'Hello world\'
```

and that's not what i want at all...

does someone know the solution ? thanks !

Comment: Hello Sigggg and welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you tried with double quotes? Like this `"'${1}'"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
command(){
    $(randomCommand -a "'${1}'")
}

command "Hello world"
```

Should result in:

```
randomCommand -a 'Hello world'
```